# Making sure a user's input matches characters generated by my program

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

**This is for Homework**

I'm programming a simplified game of scrabble where I have my program randomly generate characters then the user would try and create a word from those generated characters, then get a score afterwards. **The issue I'm having is making sure the user is actually using the characters provided.** I have no clue on how to approach this problem. I don't need any code but hints would be appreciated or even links for a point to start at. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT** - About half my program [The part that creates the letter set]

```
 void generate_letter_set(int letter_set[] , int size_let , int num_let)  
 {
  int arr[N];

const char let[] = 
{'K','J','X','Q','Z','B','C','M','P','F','H','V','W','Y','G','L','S','U','D','N','R','T','O','A','I','E'};

const int freq[] = 
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 12 };

int score[] =
{ 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

        int index = 0; 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++) {
for(int f = 0 ; f < freq[i]; f++) {
        arr[index++] = let[i];  //All the 96 letters are stored in let[i]
            //printf("%c " , let[i]);  // Created the letter bank for all the letters 

 } 
}       int letter;
        printf("Your letters are: ");
    for(int l = 0; l < 7; l++){
            letter = rand() % 97; 
        printf("%c ", arr[letter]);


                                }   
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: I'll put in my first function

Comment: You look at the characters they use; you compare them with the characters you provided.  If there's a mismatch, you call 'foul'.  You might think about sorting the characters you gave in alphabetic order, and the characters returned, and then work through the lists.  Don't forget that blanks can be any character in full Scrabble; it isn't clear whether you have to deal with that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry, I don't have to deal with blanks. So I think I know what you're saying. I left out a function because I didn't want to post the entirety of my project. Anyways, I have all the characters given to a user stored in an array i created called 'word[]' So you're saying I make a for loop, compare the letters given and the letters entered. Use boolean values (0's and 1's) then that may or may not compare all the letters. That's what you're saying, correct?

Comment: More or less, yes.  No blanks makes life easier.  You just have to make sure that if you pass out 2 letters A, the user doesn't try to spell BANANA.

Comment: Consider building a frequency table of the letters you randomly assign to the user. Ie: an array 26 elements long where each entry in the array is an integer representing how many of those letters the user has (most will be zero).

Comment: I see you already have a `freq[]` array. The frequency table I am referring to is similar but only counts the letters randomly handed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to search an array for certain characters.  The basis of what you need is a very simple search function.

One simple solution would be to use two nested `for` loops.  Assuming let[] is your 'haystack' to check and word is your user input:

```
// Check each letter of word[]...
for (int ii = 0; ii <= lengthOfUserInput; ii++)
{
    char characterToValidate = word[ii];
    // ... for not existing in let[]
    for (int jj = 0; jj <= lengthOfStringOfValues; jj++)
    {
        if (characterToValidate != let[jj])
    }
}
```