# How to get a program to compare two arrays then see if the two arrays have the same characters

Tags: c, arrays, boolean

**This is for Homework**
So I have to program a simple game of scrabble. I have comments throughout my whole program but I'll explain what I wanted to do towards the end of this post.

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdbool.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <time.h> 
#define N 96

 int main() {
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
int letter_set = N , size_let = 7 , num_let = 7 , max_size_word = 7 , size_letter_set = 7, size_word, arr[N];
char word [7]; 
printf("This program plays a game of scrabble.\n");

generate_letter_set(letter_set , size_let , num_let, arr);
read_word(word, max_size_word);
check_word(word, size_word, letter_set, size_letter_set, arr);

return 0;
}


 void generate_letter_set(int letter_set[] , int size_let , int num_let, int arr[])  
{


const char let[26] = 
{'K','J','X','Q','Z','B','C','M','P','F','H','V','W','Y','G','L','S','U','D','N','R','T','O','A','I','E'};

int freq[26] = 
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 12 };

const int score[26] =
{ 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    int index = 0; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++) {
            for(int f = 0 ; f < freq[i]; f++) {
                arr[index++] = let[i];  //All the 96 letters are stored in let[i]
            //printf("%c " , let[i]);  // Created the letter bank for all the letters 

        } 
    }       

    int letter;
        printf("Your letters are: ");
            for(int l = 0; l < 7; l++){
                letter = rand() % 97;   //Gives the user their letters all the letters are from arr[letter] 
            printf("%c ", arr[letter]);


        }   

 }
   int read_word(char word[], int max_size_word) {

{
          int c = 0, let_count = 0;
            printf("\nPlease enter your word: ");
        char input = toupper(getchar());
                for(c = 0; c < max_size_word; c++) {

    if(input != '\n')
{       word[c] = input;   
            let_count++;
    }
    else if(input == '\n')
    input = toupper(getchar());     //The word the user entered is in word[c]
                                    }

return let_count;
 }

    }
 int check_word(char word[], int size_word, int letter_set[], int 
  size_letter_set, int arr[]) {
//Figure out how to pass two arrays through the functions
//Pass word[c] into this function 
//Pass arr[letter] into this function then compare the two arrays
//Make it so the user has to enter less than 7 chars
for (int a; a < 7; a++) {

    if (word[a] != arr[a]) {
printf("Use your letters");
 }

}


 return 1;
}
```

So my only issue in this program is how I'm going to get my 'check_word' function to work. This function has to check if the user entered the letters that are provided. In a game of scrabble you get 7 letters, and the array that has the 7 letters given to the user is stored in **(arr[])** Then the in the 'read_word' function is the letters the user entered. The letters that are entered are stored in **word[]**. So my intuition to check if the user actually used the letters from **arr[]** was to make a conditional statement that compared the two arrays **arr[]** and **word[]**. However I realize that would check if the user actually used every single letter and I just have to check if the user used any letters that weren't provided. I'm lost on how to make this happen and any help would be appreciated! Also please let me know in the comments if any clarification is needed, also I apologize for the huge post.

Comment: Didn't you already post this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901918/making-sure-a-users-input-matches-characters-generated-by-my-program  You can edit your post to clarify further instead of reposting.  Like I posted there, build a frequency table of the letters the user has been provided and check them against the letters in the proposed word.

Comment: @MFisherKDX , sorry I'm a little New to this website I didn't realize there's an edit option, but wouldn't the frequency table have every single letter possible in a game of scrabble?

Comment: `letter = rand() % 97;` is a poor way to select a letter in the range `'A'` to `'Z'`. Also, the letter bag should have specific number of each letter tile, so I suggest you find an alogrithm that picks one tile at random and removes it from the bag. The tile needs to be a `struct` with its character and score. Select one tile `struct` from the bag (an array) according to how many are left, and adjust the array.

Comment: @Weather Vane I understand what you're saying but for this project it isn't necessary because the user will only play scrabble once so decrementing letters from the array wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I can see you attempted to model the number of tiles available with `int freq[26]` but still, the way to go is with an array of `struct` in the letter bag.

Comment: @chrisHG.  Build a frequency table of just the letters that have been provided to the user.  So if the user has been provided: R S T L N E E, the freq['R'] = 1, freq['S] = 1, freq['T'] = 1, freq['L'] = 1, freq['N'] = 1 and freq['E'] = 2.  Now it should be easy to check the words "NESTLE" and "REEL" are valid.

Comment: BTW, @WeatherVane and I are talking about 2 *distinct* things ... which I can see might be confusing.

Comment: It is not about *frequency* but about *availabilty* (and definitely not how many times you play the game). There is only one `'Z'` in the bag so after picking that tile, it is not about probabilty of drawing another `'Z'`. The probabality is only about the tiles in the bag.

Comment: @xing so set up a for loop that goes though every element in the array that is user entered, then check if that element is present in the letter bank. How would you check the letter the user entered against the each character in the letter bank?

Comment: I would advise you to drop that approach altogether, and have a think about a `struct` based approach with a certain number of each tile being available, and removed from the pool when picked. The problem of drawing a tile from a bag is very similar to drawing a card from a deck, where  there is only one of each card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As letters are selected from all letters and from your letters, they are swapped to the end of the array and the number of available letters is decremented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 98

void generate_letter_set( char arr[], int *all, char yourletters[], int limit);
void read_word(char word[], int max_size_word);
int check_word(char word[], char yourletters[]);

int main ( void) {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    char arr[N] = "";
    char yourletters [8] = "";
    char word [8]= "";
    int pool = N;//available letters
    int size_let = 7;
    int num_let = 7;
    int max_size_word = 7;
    int size_letter_set = 7;
    int size_word;
    printf("This program plays a game of scrabble.\n");

    printf ( "pool of available letters is %d\n", pool);
    generate_letter_set( arr, &pool, yourletters, max_size_word);
    printf ( "\npool of available letters is now %d\n", pool);
    printf ( "\nyour letters %s\n", yourletters);
    read_word(word, max_size_word);
    if ( ( check_word(word, yourletters))) {
        printf ( "word %s is usable from your letters %s\n", word, yourletters);
    }
    else {
        printf ( "word %s is not usable from your letters %s\n", word, yourletters);
    }

    return 0;
}

void generate_letter_set(char arr[], int *all,char yourletters[], int limit)
{
    const char let[26] = {"KJXQZBCMPFHVWYGLSUDNRTOAIE"};

    int freq[26] =
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 12 };

    const int score[26] =
    { 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++) {
        for(int f = 0 ; f < freq[i]; f++) {
            arr[index++] = let[i];  //All the 98 letters are stored in let[i]
        }
    }

    int letter;
    char swap;
    printf("Your letters are: ");
    for(int l = 0; l < limit; l++){
        letter = rand() % *all;   //Gives the user their letters all the letters are from arr[letter]
        printf("%c ", arr[letter]);
        yourletters[l] = arr[letter];
        *all = *all - 1;//deduct from the number of available letters
        swap = arr[letter];//swap letter to end of array
        arr[letter] = arr[*all];
        arr[*all] = swap;
    }

}

void read_word(char word[], int max_size_word) {
    int c = 0;
    printf("\nPlease enter your word: ");
    for(c = 0; c < max_size_word; c++) {
        int input = toupper(getchar());

        if(input != '\n')
        {
            word[c] = input;
        }
        else if(input == '\n')
            break;     //The word the user entered is in word[c]
   }

    return;
}

int check_word(char word[], char valid[]) {
    char *check = word;//check is first letter in word
    char swap = ' ';
    int match = 0;
    int len = strlen ( valid);
    //Figure out how to pass two arrays through the functions
    //Pass word[c] into this function
    //Pass arr[letter] into this function then compare the two arrays
    //Make it so the user has to enter less than 7 chars

    while ( *check) {//loop until check points to '\0'
        for ( int each = 0; each < len; each++) {
            match = 0;
            //this printf is just for show and can be removed
            printf ( "check %c in %.*s\n", *check, len, valid);
            if ( *check == valid[each]) {
                match = 1;
                swap = valid[each];//swap letter to end of array
                valid[each] = valid[len - 1];
                valid[len - 1] = swap;
                len--;//deduct from avaiable letters
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( !match) {
            return 0;
        }
        check++;//next letter to check
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> **So my only issue in this program is how I'm going to get my 'check_word' function to work.** This function has to check if the user entered the letters that are provided. In a game of scrabble you get 7 letters, and the array that has the 7 letters given to the user is stored in (arr[]) Then the in the 'read_word' function is the letters the user entered.

There are many ways to solve this problem.  Here is one way.  Build a frequency table of the letters that are provided to the user.  So if the user has been provided: `R S T L N E E`, then `freq['R'] = 1`, `freq['S] = 1`, `freq['T'] = 1`, `freq['L'] = 1`, `freq['N'] = 1` and `freq['E'] = 2`.  All the other values in `freq` are 0.  Then when the user enters a word, you can loop over each letter and subtract 1 from the frequency table of that letter.  If any value is less than 0, then the word is invalid.

However, you have another problem in your code regarding randomizing the input -- ie: dealing the letters to the user.  @Weathervane has made a few comments there that might help.  Consider putting all the letters into a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) (or more properly a [bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) -- since letters can be repeated) and randomly drawing a letter from the bag.  Repeat 7 times (or until the bag is empty).

Comment: Okay I understand the approach it makes sense, but programming wise would you run through the array of given letters with a loop. Then how is the frequency of each letter set to 1?

Comment: Yes.  Initialize a frequency table to all 0's.  Run through each of the given letters with a loop.  If the letter is 'A', then increment `freq['A']`.  Now its 1.

Comment: For clarification, the frequency table you're talking about is different than the One I used within my first function?

Comment: Yes.  It's different, but similar.  I saw that and realized the confusion.  Your `freq` array specifies the frequency of the entire population of letters both used and unused.  The table I am referring to specifies the frequency of only the letters currently available for the user to play.  If this is too confusing and you understand @xing 's method better, use his method.

Comment: I get your method. The only part I'm confused about is how I would go through every single character in the array of given letters and set the frequency for every letter to 1. Then I would use a conditional statement to check if any letter entered by the user is less than 1 by decrementing the frequency table?

Answer (score 1):

I coded your task, if you are interested, I can add comments to the code.

How it works:

1. The bag of tiles created in the beginning. Tiles are stored in the array, where indexes are **ascii** codes of letters. `A` is 65, `B` is 66, `Z` is 90. So, we are needed array of 90 elements, where only indexes from 66 to 90 will be used, others unneeded. So, I did the next trick - subtract 65 from the **ascii** code of letter and get following indexes: `A` - 0, `B` - 1, `Z` - 26. Now, array of 26 elements only is needed. The advantage of this method is the detection of the letter availability with the O(1) efficiency. Does the array contains the `M` letter? - check array[12], if it is non-zero, the letter contained, else does not contained. Two `for` loops are unnecessary.
2. Rack is created and filled from the bag. It is also array[26], but have only 7 tiles inside it, other items are zero.
3. Prints the rack content and waits the user word. User should write a word, using letters from the rack.
4. Checks, does this word is valid - iterate through words letters and check, does this letter is contained in the rack. If yes - the letter is removed from rack and next letter of the word is processed. For example, the user have entered the word `cat`. **Ascii** codes are `67`,`65`,`84` (uppercase). Subtracting 65 from each code, we obtain `2`,`0`,`19`. Does this items exists (non-zero) in the rack array? Yes - the word is valid. No - non-valid, "Try again". If the rack have less than 7 tiles, it refilled from the bag.
5. The game continues as long as there are tiles in the bag or in the rack.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CNT 26
//////////////////
typedef struct tile {
    char letter;
    int amount;
    int points;
} tile;
/////////////
typedef struct tiles_set {
    int tiles_num;
    int storage_size;
    tile storage[CNT];
} tiles_set;

void check_user_word(char *word, tiles_set rack_copy, tiles_set *rack_ptr); 
void fill_rack(tiles_set *rack, int to_size); 
void print_set(tiles_set set); 
void bag_init(); 

tiles_set bag;

int main() {
    int rack_size = 7;
    char *user_word;

    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    bag_init();

    tiles_set rack;
    rack.storage_size = CNT;
    rack.tiles_num = 0;
    memset(rack.storage, 0, sizeof(rack.storage));

    while(bag.tiles_num > 0 || rack.tiles_num > 0) {
        fill_rack(&rack, rack_size);

        puts("Rack:");
        print_set(rack);
        printf("\nWrite your word: \n");

        fgets(user_word, rack_size + 2, stdin);
        check_user_word(user_word, rack, &rack);
    }
    return 0;
}

void check_user_word(char *word, tiles_set rack_copy, tiles_set *rack_ptr) {
    int i, ch, len;

    if(!strchr(word, '\n')) {
        printf("The word should be less or equal to the amount of tiles in the rack - %d tiles\n", rack_ptr->tiles_num);
        while(((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));
        puts("Try again.");
        return;
    }

    len = strlen(word) - 1;

    char letter;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        letter = toupper(word[i]) - 65;

        if(rack_copy.storage[letter].amount) {
            rack_copy.storage[letter].amount--;
            rack_copy.tiles_num--;
        } else {
            puts("You should use letters only from the rack. Try again.");
            return;
        }
    }
    *rack_ptr = rack_copy;
}

void fill_rack(tiles_set *rack, int to_size) {
    int i;  
    char letter;
    int cnt = to_size - rack->tiles_num;
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        if(bag.tiles_num <= 0) {
            puts("Tiles in the bag ended.");
            return;
        }

        do {
            letter = rand() / (RAND_MAX / bag.storage_size + 1);
        } while(!bag.storage[letter].amount);

        rack->storage[letter].letter = bag.storage[letter].letter;
        rack->storage[letter].amount++;
        rack->storage[letter].points = bag.storage[letter].points;
        rack->tiles_num++;  

        bag.storage[letter].amount--;
        bag.tiles_num--;
    }
}

void bag_init() {
    const char letters[CNT] = 
    {'K','J','X','Q','Z','B','C','M','P','F','H','V','W','Y','G','L','S','U','D','N','R','T','O','A','I','E'};
    int freq[CNT] = 
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 12 };
    const int points[CNT] =
    { 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    bag.storage_size = CNT;
    bag.tiles_num = 98;

    int i;
    int letter_index;
    for(i = 0; i < bag.storage_size; i++) {
        letter_index = letters[i] - 65;
        bag.storage[letter_index].letter = letters[i];
        bag.storage[letter_index].amount= freq[i];
        bag.storage[letter_index].points = points[i];
    }
}

void print_set(tiles_set set) {
    int i, cnt;
    for(i = 0; i < set.storage_size; i++) {
        cnt = set.storage[i].amount;
        while(cnt > 0) {
            printf("%c ", set.storage[i].letter);
            cnt--;
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
```